# Does a library for prime-related functions exist for Python?

Tags: python, primes

I've just implemented the [Miller-Rabin-Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) and a simple function for factorizing numbers. Both could be done better and at least the Miller-Rabin-Test is well-known.

So could you please tell me if a Python-Library, that implements such common prime functions  exists or why no such library exists?

Comment: I used [primality](https://pypi.org/project/primality/) today to check whether a 128-byte number is prime. It's quite fast, producing the answer seemingly instantaneously.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[gmpy2](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy) supports a variety of pseudoprime tests. The Miller-Rabin test is available as `gmpy2.is_strong_prp()`.

gmpy2 does not have any factorization code yet.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of gmpy2. The primality tests are based on code from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpzprp/files/

Answer (score 27):

I just discovered `isprime` from the [**SymPy** package](http://sympy.org/):

```py
import sympy
print sympy.isprime(10)
```

Output:

```
False
```

---

Not to confuse with `prime`, which returns the n-th prime number:

```
import sympy
print sympy.prime(10)
```

Output:

```
29
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that there exists such a module dedicated to prime functions in the standard library, but of course there are plenty of people who have written primality tests and such.

One library that is geared towards multiple-precision arithmetic, but which has several functions for primes (such as `is_prime()` and `next_prime()`) is [`GMPY2`](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/). The [documentation](http://readthedocs.org/docs/gmpy2/en/latest/) is also available.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for implementations of algorithms, check out [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code). The website has many implementations in Python. You could definitely piece together your own library for your personal need.

Comment: I am explicitly not looking for implementations. I have already implemented the code, but I generally prefer loading a function from a module that has been reviewed than writing it myself, especially if it is something well-knowen like Miller-Rabin.

Answer (score 0):

[Primes-Library-Python](https://github.com/MagikCow/Primes-Library-Python) is an in development python library. Good for basic functions and very fast for the bigger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I created a library with many, many functions (see the README), but it's most important is that it includes Alpertons ECM library so you can factor with Alperton's Engine (Even under Termux under Android) from ipython3:

https://github.com/oppressionslayer/primalitytest/

Just watch the video at the beginning of the README and see how easy it is to get it working with Alperton's C library.

to use it, just use from sfactorint import p2ecm from the primality directory. To get access to Alperton's ECM, follow these steps:

```
cd calculators
make
cd ..
```

And that's it, sfactorint then uses Alpertons ECM SIQS for factorization. I plan to make a pip install that does the make step automatically, so keep watching if you interested in it.

Here's a sample 60 digit number factor from it, i do the same one on an Android in the video at about the same speed:

```
In [22]: import time   
    ...: start = time.time()   
    ...: print(p2ecm(632459103267572196107100983820469021721602147490918660274601))   
    ...: end = time.time()   
    ...: print(end-start)    
    ...:                                                                                                                                                       
[650655447295098801102272374367, 972033825117160941379425504503]
5.197108030319214
```