# Finding the nearest prime number in python 3.7

Tags: python

I have a coding assignment in which I need to ask the user to enter a number n, then output the prime number closest to n. If there are two primes equally close to n, then output the smaller of the two primes. Currently I have the code posted below which obviously isn't correct, but I can't get the correct solution.

```
n = int(input("enter a number: "))
x = n
y = n
for i in range(2, n):
    while n % i  == 0:
            x += 1
            y -= 1
            if n % i != 0 and (x-n) < (n-y):
                print("The prime number closest to", n, "is", x)
            elif n % i != 0 and (n-y) < (x-n):
                print ("The prime number closest to" , n, "is", y)
    else:
            print ("The prime number closest to" , n, "is", n)
```

Comment: first try simple algorithm to find prime numbers then make it fit your problem. In your code some wrong logics for example :
```while n % i == 0: 
            if n%i!=0 ... : 
```
this expression will be always false so you cant access to x y prime numbers because your `n%i` is always  `0`

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to tackle this type of problem by breaking it into parts:

1. Write a function `is_prime` that takes a number as its argument and returns `True` if it's prime.  The standard way to do this is to repeatedly test smaller numbers to see if they work as factors (it looks like your code is trying to do something along these lines already).
2. Once you get `n` from the user, iterate over nearby numbers (similar to what you're doing with `x` and `y`) and check them with `is_prime`.  If neither is prime, go to the next nearest numbers and repeat until you find something.

Each of these parts (separately) will involve writing a loop.  Your current code doesn't quite work because you're trying to do everything in a single loop.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code:

[credit for the `is_prime` function in this stackoverflow answer by @alf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019343/primality-test-in-python)

```
from itertools import count


def is_prime(x):
    for i in range(2, x-1):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True


def closest_prime(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 1
    closest = 0
    for p1 in count(n, step=-1):
        if is_prime(p1):
            closest = p1
            break
    for p2 in count(n, step=1):
        if is_prime(p2):
            if p2 - n < n - p1:
                closest = p2
                break
            else:
                closest = p1
                break
    return closest


# Tests
print(closest_prime(10))  # => 11
print(closest_prime(20))  # => 19
print(closest_prime(30))  # => 29
print(closest_prime(-100))  # => 1
print(closest_prime(0))  # => 1
print(closest_prime(1))  # => 1
```

**Edit: add demo to print in shell**

```
# Demo
n = int(input("enter a number: "))
print("The prime number closest to", n, "is", closest_prime(n))
```

Comment: I understand this, although I need it to be able to print in the shell. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @lividpoison check out the edit if that's what you mean.

Comment: ah I realize I made a stupid mistake. I was wondering why it wouldn't originally let me print in the shell but I figured it out. Thanks anyways though for the help