# How to speed up a python program which verifies prime numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, calculation

I wrote this simple python 3.7 code for verifying prime numbers however I'm seeing bottlenecks with numbers over 10 digits long.  I know that's weak, but I think there is hope for this piece of code with your help.

Is it possible to **speed up** this program to make it **run super fast**?

The program states False for composites and True for prime numbers.  For instance this number (1235468711) takes 16 seconds to report False which equals a composite number.

By the way (a) has to remain in that state for the code to work.

I have tried compact mapping and no speed enhancement was found.

Here is the code:

```py
p = int(input('Enter a prime number and if True its prime: '))

def prime(*kwargs):
    for i in kwargs:
        yield i 
k = (2 * p)

a = prime((2 ** (p + 1) - 1) % k)

for i in a:
    if i == 3:
        print(i is not False, "| If True number is prime!")
    else:
        print(False, "| If False number is not prime!")
```

Comment: I am assuming you know that this is a [probable prime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), and for example, 341, will mistakenly be reported as prime?

Comment: Isn’t the line `i is not False` invalid syntax? In any case, that should just be written `i`. Can you explain how you’re actually testing primality? I don’t understand your code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8019343/2750819 for various implementations.

Comment: @Alexander,  I sort of just came across this while I was messing with numbers while coding.  It's sort of an off shoot of 2^n-1 with a twist as you can see  2^p+1 with -1 mod 2*p

Comment: @Kent,Thanks for pointing out 341 seems to be an annoying composite!

Comment: @Edward I was throw off by the insane amount of parentheses. What are they for?

Comment: @Alexander, I believe it maintains the True and False statement to be correct since you can't change (a) or it will cease to function correctly, except for 341 as it is a probable prime test as stated by Kent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create the most compact mapping n → isprime(n) up to a limit N?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/how-to-create-the-most-compact-mapping-n-%e2%86%92-isprimen-up-to-a-limit-n)

Comment: Dont use `is` unless you understand what it does. Use `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this pseudo-prime primality test is in the line:

```
a = prime(((2**(((((p+1)))))-1))%k)
```

because it needs to compute an expensive power only to take its modulus afterwards.

However, Python does provide [`pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#pow), which can compute `a ** b % c` more efficiently as `pow(a, b, c)`.

In your case, this is not exactly the same formula as you have an extra `-1` around. Since `(a ** b - 1) % c` is in general different from `a ** b % c - 1`, you need some extra computation to reproduce your exact same formula. For example you could make use of an extra `if` i.e.:

```
x = pow(a, b, c)
x += -1 if x > 0 else c - 1
```

or add an additional modulus operation:

```
(pow(a, b, c) - 1) % c
```

To give you some benchmarks, on my machine I observe a +200x speed-up with the proposed approach:

```
p = 123456

print(((2**(((((p+1)))))-1))%(2 * p))
# 127999
print((pow(2, p + 1, 2 * p) - 1) % (2 * p))
# 127999

%timeit ((2**(((((p+1)))))-1))%(2 * p)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 466 µs per loop
%timeit (pow(2, p + 1, 2 * p) - 1) % (2 * p)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 µs per loop
```

Note that there are more efficient [(pseudo-)primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) around.